# How can I better load country specific borders (from geoJson file) of a selected country onto a leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, leaflet

Currently I have an html select tag that is populated by looping through a geoJson file (decoded using using PHP). The select option’s text is the country name and the value is it’s iso_a3 code.
When a country is selected and the button is click I’d like to load the country specific borders. Currently I’m only able to get this to work manually by using if/else if e.g:

```
var border ;

$('#btnRun').click(function() {
     let name = $('#selCountry').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "geoJson.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if (map.hasLayer(border)) {
            map.removeLayer(border);
            }
              if (name === "CAN") {
                border = L.geoJSON(result.data.border.features[1]).addTo(map);
              } else if (name === "BHS") {
                border = L.geoJSON(result.data.border.features[0]).addTo(map);
              } else if (name === "GRL") {
                border = L.geoJSON(result.data.border.features[4]).addTo(map);
              } 
          map.fitBounds(border.getBounds());
```

I’m sure this is a terrible way to do this (will need to do this for 175 countries in the file). How can I create some kind of loop that would match that option’s value (iso_a3 code) to the appropriate array to load the correct border? Or other better solutions?

my html:

```
<nav>   
   <h1>Choose a country:</h1>
   <select name="sel-country" id="selCountry"></select>
   <button id="btnRun" data-modal-target="#modal">Run</button>
</nav>
```

This code populates the options:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "geoJson.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        
        for (var i=0; i<result.data.border.features.length; i++) {
            $('#selCountry').append($('<option>', {
                value: result.data.border.features[i].properties.iso_a3,
                text: result.data.border.features[i].properties.name,
            }));
           }
        }
    });
```

my php code:

```
<?php

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;
    
    $result = file_get_contents('countryBorders.geo.json');

    $border = json_decode($result,true);
    $countryInfo = json_decode($result,true);
    
    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['executedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";

    $output['data']['border'] = $border;
    $output['data']['countryInfo'] = $countryInfo;
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

This is the data I'm using:

```
{status: {…}, data: {…}}
data:
border:
features: Array(175)
[0 … 99]
0:
geometry:
coordinates: Array(3)
0: [Array(8)]
1: [Array(6)]
2: [Array(7)]
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
type: "MultiPolygon"
__proto__: Object
properties:
iso_a2: "BS"
iso_a3: "BHS"
iso_n3: "044"
name: "Bahamas"
__proto__: Object
type: "Feature"
__proto__: Object
1: {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
2: {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
3: {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
4: {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
5: {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
6: {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
```

this continues for 175 countries....

Comment: What's in `result`?

Comment: result is the decoded json data from the php. I just added my php code if that helps.

Comment: send `result` object. I will check if there is any similarity between country code and json data

Comment: I've added part of the object just because it repeats.

Comment: so `result.data.features[0].properties.iso_a3` is country code?

Comment: I forgot to add that I declared a global variable 'border' at the top on my code.

Comment: Yeah result.data.border.features[0].properties.iso_a3 is how I'm getting the country code. the borders all work fine manually using if/else but I know its not a good way of doing this.

Comment: Answered using `filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.filter`. Something like the below example

```
const filterData = result.data.border.features.filter((a) => (a.properties.iso_a3 === name));
border = L.geoJSON(filterData[0]); 
map.fitBounds(border.getBounds());
```